# Is WebAssembly a "Reverse Polish Notation" calculator?

Tags: webassembly

As I know that there are two kinds of stack machines which are RPN and PN, so is WebAssembly a "Reverse Polish Notation" calculator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct connection between stack machines and Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) or Polish Notation (PN). You must make a distinction between ***grammar*** and ***semantics***.

You can say in your ***grammar*** that operators should come before (`add 3 5`), between (`3 add 5`) or after (`add 3 5`) their operands and the languages for those grammars would look differently. A [stack oriented language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language) can use any of the prefix/infix/postfix forms for specifying parameters and I guess in that sense they could be classified as PN or RPN languages.

The ***semanctics*** of the language - what happens when the expression is evaluated - is separated from the grammar of the language. The WebAssembly spec dictates those semantics using an abstract stack machine: for each instruction it says how many stack items are consumed and how many are added back. The language used for generating WebAssembly code can be in prefix, infix or postfix form.

The WebAssembly text format uses a S-expression prefix notation. But it could just as well have been written using infix or postfix notation. I guess S-expressions were chosen because they're easy to parse and more commonly encountered by compiler/language folks than postfix/stackoriented languages.

Comment: I originally chose S-expressions when I wrote the Wasm reference interpreter. It was because (1) Wasm was still an expression language at the time, not a stack machine, (2) there was no time or desire to bikeshed syntax, and (3) something simple and regular was preferable.